# Problema para somar valores em JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

O console me apresenta o seguinte erro:

> FUNCTION trabalhoviagemd.SUM does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Só pode ser o sql no meu prepareStatement, ajudem-me!

***Método Dao***

```
public List<ViagemBean> getListaTotalDiaria(String totalDiaira) {
    try {
        List<ViagemBean> viagens = new ArrayList<ViagemBean>();

        ConexaoMySQL.conectar();

        PreparedStatement stmt = ConexaoMySQL.getConexao()
                .prepareStatement("select SUM (valorDiaria) as total from viagem where colaborador = ? ");

        stmt.setString(1, totalDiaira);  

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            // criando o objeto viagem
            ViagemBean viagem = new ViagemBean();

            viagem.setValorDiaria(rs.getDouble("total"));

            // adicionando o objeto à lista
            viagens.add(viagem);
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        return viagens;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deixou um espaço entre a função e o parâmetro.

```
select SUM (valorDiaria)
```

Arruma para:

```
select SUM(valorDiaria)
```

Comment: Valeu cara era isso mesmo ;)